# Do I need to cover up Dwarf Fig trees in the winter time?

Tags: fruit-trees

I read that a dwarf fig can grow in zone 4 (jujube figs can't grow there), so I was wondering if I can grow dwarf fig trees in my zone well. What made me wonder is "Root is hardy anywhere, but the top will die back below 5° F".

Comment: Hi!  Would you mind writing not just which zone you're in,  but more importantly the actual temperatures you deal with?  Zones aren't always exact, plus it makes it easier for people to just read the degrees. You can  [edit] it  right into the question. That would help any time you have this type of question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figs in the north are a lot of work. You have to keep the tree small, partially uproot it and tip it over and bury it in fall, unbury it and stand it up in spring (sometimes referred to as mounding, if looking for more info on it) - or keep it in a pot and move the pot inside, or grow it in a greenhouse. The "wrapping" approach is not reliable in serious cold.

http://www.theitaliangardenproject.com/tuck-in-fig.html

http://www.theitaliangardenproject.com/michele-uncover-fig.html

http://www.theitaliangardenproject.com/wake-fig-tree.html